# element is invalid expected a string

Tags: react-native

i have created screenLogin  and i am using library formik and yup , I have created a component Appformfield, I have imported Appformfield into screenlogin

```
export default function AppFormField({ name, ...otherProps }) {
  const { handleChange, errors, setFieldTouched, touched } = useFormikContext();
  return (
    <>
      <AppTextInput
        // color="white"
        // autoCapitalize="none"
        // autoCorrect={false}
        // icon="email"
        // keyboardType="email-address"
        // placeholder="email"
        onBlur={() => setFieldTouched(name)}
        {...otherProps}
        // textContentType="emailAddress"
        onChangeText={handleChange(name)}
      />
      <ErrorMessage error={errors[name]} visible={touched[name]} />
    </>
  );
}
```

This is my screen login form in which I have imported component I don't know why I am getting this error

```
export default function ScreenLogin() {
  return (
    <ExpoScreen style={styles.container}>
      <Image style={styles.logo} source={require("../assets/logo.png")} />
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
        onSubmit={(values) => console.log(values)}
        validationSchema={validationSchema}
      >
        {({ handleChange, handleSubmit, errors, setFieldTouched, touched }) => (
          <>
            <AppFormField
              name="email"
              // color="white"
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoCorrect={false}
              icon="email"
              keyboardType="email-address"z
              placeholder="email"
              textContentType="emailAddress"
            />
            <AppFormField
              // color="white"
              name="password"
              onBlur={() => setFieldTouched("password")}
              onChangeText={handleChange("password")}
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoCorrect={false}
              icon="lock"
              placeholder="Password"
              textContentType="password"
              secureTextEntry
            />

            <AppButton title="close" color="white" onPress={handleSubmit} />
          </>
        )}
      </Formik>
    </ExpoScreen>
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: What error? Please put the text of your error in the question. Pictures of code and errors are useless.

Comment: You should check the imports of various files you use

Comment: the error says type need to be string, can you confirm it by console if you are passing the valid type to the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've imported Default exported component ErrorMessage into brackets.

[image: Ref to the picture]